# Can someone explain if this is a different function?

Tags: functions, fractions

I have a function which looks like:

$$\frac{x+10}{(x+10) (x - 9) (x - 5)}$$

The domain of the function for input x is any number except -10, 9, and 5, because it would be dividing by zero. The thing I don't quite get is that if I were to cancel out the (x+10)'s

$$\frac{1}{(x-9)(x-5)}$$

I'm told the function has changed. I know that now the domain includes -10, when before it didn't, but this seems a bit paradoxical to me because

If I were to do:

$$\frac{x+10}{(x+10) (x - 9) (x - 5)} = a$$

then

$$\frac{1}{(x - 9) (x - 5)} also = a$$

Is there a way a someone could explain this to me because it seems a bit paradoxical. The previous two equations are equal, but the functions are not?

Is it the same function but just with a different domain or is it a completely different function?

Comment: To visualise it, let's draw a graph of $1$ and $\dfrac{x+10}{x+10}$.  The only difference between two graphs is the missing point $(-10,1)$ in the later.

Comment: @GNU Supporter When I draw the graph and I get to x = -10, obviously I can't plot a point because the operation isn't defined, is that what you mean? Edit: Oops, your comment changed all of a sudden, I'm not sure if this is a bug or an edit, I'll plot again

Comment: @GNU Supporter I see your point, thanks.

Comment: I had forgotten the add the numerator. Yes, but this hole can be "completed" by taking the limit.

Comment: " I know that now the domain includes -10, when before it didn't,"  That is a change.  The function has changed.  It incluce -10 when before it didn't.  that is the only change but that *IS* a change.

Comment: "Is it the same function but just with a different domain or is it a completely different function?"  Neither.  The domain is a defining aspect of a function so a different domain makes it a different function.  "completely different", if it is to have any precise meaning, must mean more than agreeing on *every* point but one.  Unless, all different funtions are "completely" different and "completely" has no meaning, I wouldn't call these "completely different as for all $x \ne -10$ the functions take on equal values.

Answer (score 4):

In your reasoning with

$$
\frac{x+10}{(x+10)(x-9)(x-5)} = a
$$

you assumed that $a$ is a real number. This happens when $x\neq -10$. Therefore, you inadvertently assumed that $x \neq -10$, in which case the two expressions are the same.

There is no paradox. The two expressions are the same if $x\neq -10$. If $x=-10$, you can easily see that the first expression is not defined, whereas the second expression does get a real value.

Comment: I see, the distinction is becoming clearer.

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to see the difference, so the two equations I wrote aren't equal at all. That's to say, they COULD be equal, but in one case 'a' might be a real number and in another case 'a' could simply be undefined result, right?